# Is the author's code correct? - B. Stroustrup's PPP using C++: Chapter 7, Section 7.2 - Input & Output

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm learning C++ using B. Stroustrup's PPP using C++, 1st edition. This chapter 7 is an extension to chapter 6 in which a basic calculator, which takes expressions (like 1+2;) to produce output (';' is for terminating expression), is developed. (I'm using Visual Studio 2013)

In section 7.2, to improve the layout of the program for the user, the author expects this -

```
> 2+3;
=5
> 5*7;
=35
>
```

and (inputting multiple expressions)

```
> 2+3; 5*7; 2+9;
=5
> =35
> =11
>
```

by using this code -

```
main():

double val = 0;
while (cin) {
    cout << "> "; // print prompt
    Token t = ts.get(); // get token from Token_stream ts
    if (t.kind == 'q' ) break; // 'q' for quit
    if (t.kind == ';' )      // ';' to print value
        cout << "= " << val << '\n'; // print result
    else
        ts.putback(t);  // put back token in Token_stream ts
    val = expression();  // evaluate expression
}
```

But to my knowledge, this piece of code cannot generate such output and works something like this,

1. Read a token
2. If it is to quit or print some value, then do it, else put that
   token back into the Token_stream.
3. Then, calculate the value of an expression (assuming that there is
   an expression entered by the user). If there is no expression/token to read, the program just waits for the input (in `primary()` function).
4. After the expression is evaluated, go to step 1.

So, the value of the expression will only be printed when a `';'` is detected by `main()`, and `>` will be printed every time, even before printing the value of the expression, and even the output for a simple expression, `1+2;` by my program is -

```
> 1+2;
> =3
2+3;
> =5
_
```

with cursor (underscore is used intentionally) in 3rd line.

So, am I correct that the author is using the wrong code? or am I simply out of my mind and something else is there too which I'm unable to see?

[Here](http://ideone.com/io7WFk) is the complete code for the calculator.

[Here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h) is the library `std_lib_facilities.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not crazy.

It's not unheard of for published books to have bugs. Often times, the corresponding website for a book will have an online "errata" sheet that contains all the corrections pending for the next printing.

I just checked.  I found a few typos on Stroustrup's website itself.  Here is the link to the errata for his book: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2errata.html

I didn't see anything for chapter 7.  But if you are certain you have found a bug, do send him an email. There's a chance he might reply back and thank you.

I think the block of code you have is only marginally bugged because of this line:

```
cout << "> "; // print prompt
```

It prints the `>` char on every token consumption.

I think this is more reasonable:

```
double val = 0;

cout << "> "; // print prompt the first time.

while (cin)
{
    Token t = ts.get();              // get token from Token_stream ts

    if (t.kind == 'q' )
    {
        break;          // 'q' for quit
    }

    if (t.kind == ';' )  // ';' to print value
    {   
        cout << "= " << val << '\n'; // print result
        cout << "> ";                // print new prompt
    }
    else
    {
        ts.putback(t);  // put back token in Token_stream ts
    }

    val = expression();  // evaluate expression
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And if I'm not wrong, your code will prompt only to read an expression or `'q'` or something after reading `';'` when there is a value to be printed ?

Comment: I think I simply modified the code to only print the `>` character after a value is printed.

Comment: Good catch. I had just pasted your code. If you copied that out of the book, then that is a definite bug!

Comment: It is certainly a typo. I don't even remember whether I copied or wrote it myself while writing the question but it's hilarious that I noticed it first in your answer rather than in my question. And no, there is no such bug in the book's code. I've fixed it in my question too. :)